# What could cause the 'L1' button to stop working, and is it possible to fix?

Tags: ps3, technical-issues, controllers

I accidentally let the controller fall from my hand and now the <kbd>L1</kbd> button isn't working. (which is terrible, because I love FIFA).

What can I do? is it possible to fix?

Comment: you can always buy a new controller...

Comment: Give me the money

Comment: @user61349 - as money's the issue I've made this question more about troubleshooting & potentially fixing the controller. I can't guarantee that you'll get a response (I dunno if it's possible), but it would help if you could give some more info. Does the button still 'press' or is it jammed? can you hear rattling inside?

Comment: We don't really do hardware repair here, but if you want us to give any advice, you're going to have to give us more details. It can be fixable with some glue, duct tape or even just fiddling some bits. You are definitely going to have to take your controller apart and inspect the damaged part.

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann - we do perform diagnosis and troubleshooting however. (I think it'd be a bit above and beyond to ask members to visit other members' places to fix their stuff ;))

Answer (score 2):

More often than not it is possible to fix a broken button in a controller. The required work to fix said problem varies with the level of broken you're dealing with. First off you're going to need the proper tools, at the very least a small headed phillips screwdiver to remove the screws holding your controller together.

If the damage is mechanical you can buy the parts neccesary (more often than not) from a local hardware store to fix it, if your hardware store doesn't carry the parts you have several other options but the most reliable would be to search the internet, perhaps ebay.

If the damage is in the board somehow you would first need some knowhow on what you're looking at to even be sure what's broken, then have the rest of the knowhow to fix it. At this level of repair you're probably going to need a soldering gun.